# Is there a mistake in the way $\alpha$ was defined in a solution to Spivak's Calculus - Ch 23 - 5) (c) ? - Solution Verification

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, solution-verification

The following is a question in *Spivak's Calculus - Ch 23 - 5 (c)*. I included all of question $5$ to provide completeness. I also have the solution which I was close to working out partially, but could not figure out how to gensralize/formalize things

[image]

Solution to (c):

[image]

So when I was working out things, I was getting a pattern very similar to what results after dividing by the defined $\alpha$, but I wasn't able to actually put things together with regards to actually defining the term $\alpha$. When trying to work backwards and see how this solution comes together I'm having trouble actually applying the $\alpha$. I thought I had deduced (even though it appears incorrectly) that the general form of $\alpha$ could be written as:

$$\alpha = \sum_{j = 0}^{k}10^{k-j}a_{j+1}$$

To attempt to see this in action I tried to prove a case using a partial sum. To get enough terms to see something occurring I used $n = 6$ and $k = 3$. With this being the case I get a partial sum of the form:

$$S_{6} = 10^{-1}a_{1} + 10^{-2}a_{2} + 10^{-3}a_{3} + 10^{-4}a_{4} + 10^{-5}a_{5} + 10^{-6}a_{6}$$

And calculating $\alpha$

$$\alpha_{3} = 10^{3}a_{1} + 10^{2}a_{2} + 10a_{3} + a_{4}$$

So using $\alpha_{3}$, I attempted to get $S_{6}$ out of it or at least something very close to it. I went up to the $\frac{1}{10^{3k}}$ term.

After some algebraic manipulation I arrive at:

$$a_{1}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{10^{3}} + \frac{1}{10^{6}}\bigg) + a_{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10^{4}} + \frac{1}{10^{7}}\bigg) + a_{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{10^{2}} + \frac{1}{10^{5}} + \frac{1}{10^{8}}\bigg) + a_{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{10^{3}} + \frac{1}{10^{6}} + \frac{1}{10^{9}}\bigg)$$

With a bit of rewriting:

$$a_{1}\bigg(\frac{10^{6} + 10^{3} + 10^{0}}{10^{6}}\bigg) + a_{2}\bigg(\frac{10^{7} + 10^{3} + 10^{0}}{10 ^{7}}\bigg) \cdots$$

From here I was hoping to be able to see the powers of $10$ appear. For instance I was hoping to work out something along the lines of

$$a_{1}\bigg(\frac{10^{6} + 10^{3} + 10^{0}}{10^{6}}\bigg) = a_{1}10^{-1}$$

Maybe this does come about if I used more terms, but I'm not sure and this is why I'm here. What am I missing to get the expression I'm working on into the same form as the partial sum?

A second question: In the solution in using the geometric series I'm not sure how they got the final result because when I work it out I get:

$$\frac{\alpha}{10^{k}} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{10}} = \frac{\alpha}{10^{k}} \cdot \frac{1}{\frac{9}{10}} = \frac{\alpha}{10^{k}} \cdot \frac{10}{9} = \frac{\alpha}{9\cdot10^{k-1}}$$.

So what gives?

Comment: There’s a typo/error. If you look at the power of $10$ plus the index in the definition of $\alpha$, they all add up to $k$ except for the first summand, where you have $10^ka_1$, where the power $k$ added to the index is $k+1$. Starting from the other end, the definition should read $$\alpha = a_k + 10^1a_{k-1}+10^2a_{k-2}+\cdots + 10^{k-1}a_1.$$
That will make it come out right.

Comment: Ok I could see that working, I'll flush it out, but that wouldn't have an effect on the second question I asked. What happened there?

Comment: There’s another typo there (the $\alpha$ disappears in the second line and reappears in the third), and your computations seem correct to me. Their final formula would give $.1111\cdots=\frac{9}{1}$, when it is actually $\frac{1}{9}$, as you compute.

Comment: Nice. So one last question. Playing around enough, I would've probably eventually ended up with something similar to the $\alpha$, but I wouldn't have thought about rewriting the infinite series in this alternate form and it being an infinite series I could be stuck forever in attempting to figure it out. I don't think there is an easy answer to this, but how would I know or what should I be asking myself on a question like this be able to make the jump to being able/comfortable with defining an object like $\alpha$.....also Thank you for your help.

Comment: Practice and experience. There are other ways of doing this, this is but one of them.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I'm having one issue in working out the terms. How do I work out $a_{1}\bigg(\frac{10^{6} + 10^{3} + 10^{0}}{10^{7}}\bigg)$ to get $a_{1}10^{-1}$? ...I'm having trouble simplifying the expression, I don't think I've encountered having to rewrite something of this form before.

Comment: I don’t know what you are doing or how do you get to that or why you would want to (or expect to) get to $a_110^{-1}$ (what you have is certainly not equal to that). At this point, you’d probably be better served asking separately, showing what you are doing, rather than trying to cram it into an already-too-long comment thread.

Comment: Ok, will do. I just felt since it was revolving around the same question to try and keep it self contained.