# Working out the algebra to establish decimal representation of a number from infinite series. - - Spivak - Ch 23 - 5 (c) - Proof assistance

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, solution-verification

The question I have is directly related to an earlier question I posted: [Is there a mistake in the way $\alpha$ was defined in a solution to Spivak's Calculus - Ch 23 - 5) (c) ? - Solution Verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869056/is-there-a-mistake-in-the-way-alpha-was-defined-in-a-solution-to-spivaks-cal)

It was suggested to ask the other issue I had in a separate post. So the post here revolves around the algebra I'm using to try and attain a term from a partial sum. Here is the body of the original post, which hopefully gives context to what I'm doing:

The following is a question in *Spivak's Calculus - Ch 23 - 5 (c)*. I included all of question $5$ to provide completeness. I also have the solution which I was close to working out partially, but could not figure out how to gensralize/formalize things

[image]

Solution to (c):

[image]

So when I was working out things, I was getting a pattern very similar to what results after dividing by the defined $\alpha$, but I wasn't able to actually put things together with regards to actually defining the term $\alpha$. When trying to work backwards and see how this solution comes together I'm having trouble actually applying the $\alpha$.

To attempt to see this in action I tried to prove a case using a partial sum. To get enough terms to see something interesting occurring I used $n = 6$ and $k = 3$. With this being the case I get a partial sum of the form:

$$S_{6} = 10^{-1}a_{1} + 10^{-2}a_{2} + 10^{-3}a_{3} + 10^{-4}a_{4} + 10^{-5}a_{5} + 10^{-6}a_{6}$$

Defining $\alpha_{3}$ the right way:

$$\alpha_{3} = 10^{2}a_{1} + 10^{}a_{2} + a_{3} $$

So using $\alpha_{3}$, I attempted to get $S_{6}$ out of it or at least something very close to it. I went up to the $\frac{1}{10^{3k}}$ term.

After some algebraic manipulation I arrive at:

$$a_{1}\bigg(\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10^{4}} + \frac{1}{10^{7}}\bigg) + a_{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{10^{2}} + \frac{1}{10^{5}} + \frac{1}{10^{8}}\bigg) + a_{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{10^{3}} + \frac{1}{10^{6}} + \frac{1}{10^{9}}\bigg) $$

So for simplicity let's focus on the $a_{1}$ term. For that I was hoping after performing the algebra I would arrive at:

$$a_{1}\bigg(\frac{10^{6} + 10^{3} + 10^{0}}{10^{7}}\bigg) = a_{1}10^{-1}$$

But I haven't been able to derive that conclusion. What am I missing to do to be able to got from $a_{1}\bigg(\frac{10^{6} + 10^{3} + 10^{0}}{10^{7}}\bigg)$ to $a_{n}10^{-1}$?

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  You don't give any context but it appears that the $a_i$ are just the digits in some integer $\alpha$.  In any case, there only appear to be $k$ of them.  So...your infinite sum is finite, no?  If you meant something else, you should edit your post to clarify.

Comment: I'll edit my post to give more clarity.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you wrote out a clear, numerical example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: For a concrete question, I have no idea how the indices are meant to work in your definition of $\alpha$.  Say $k=2$.  Then, do you get $\alpha=10^2a_1+10a_1+a_2$?  Something else?  Seems weird for $a_1$ to appear twice.  Did you maybe mean to start with $10^ka_0$?

Comment: @lulu. I rewrote and added a lot more detail to give context

Comment: Ok, but your proposed solution makes no sense. Just argue that, if $S$ is your decimal, then $10^nS=m+S$ where $m$ is an integer. I'm assuming that $S$ is a periodic decimal...if it is only eventually periodic then you will have to multiply by a bigger power of $10$, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Well I wasn't trying to get a solution, I was trying to workout a concrete example as you mentioned to see things fall into place.

Comment: I can't follow what you wrote at all.  For a numerical example, if $S=.123123123\cdots$ then $10^3S=123+S$.

Comment: Let me see if I can explain it better. See in the solution line where $\frac{\alpha}{10^{k}} + \frac{\alpha}{10^{2k}} + \frac{\alpha}{10^{k}} + \cdots$? So I took the $\alpha_{3}$ that I had defined and plugged it into that expression. So what I was hoping to occur was to obtain the expression of $S_{6}$ from the expression with the $\alpha_{3}$. I was trying to reverse engineer things to see them work

Comment: Take the numerical example I gave.  For it, we have $n=3$.  Note that if you take $S=.\overline {a_1a_2a_3}$ then $10^3S=10^2a_1+10a_2+a_3+S$  which certainly tells us that $S$ is rational.  But there was nothing special about $n=3$ here.